# linux : monit : iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, monit

Under linux, at least centos and I think also debian, there is a "iptables" listed in the daemons.
But it is really a script to load and save them, it doesn' start a process, neither write a pidfile.

How can I check iptables up and running with monit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CentOS 6 and earlier you're correct about it using `iptables`.  CentOS 7 uses `firewalld`.

To monitor either using Monit you can use [PROGRAM-STATUS-TEST](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#PROGRAM-STATUS-TEST).  There are several methods to ascertain the status of `iptables`.

One method to get the status of `iptables` in CentOS 6 is to use

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables status
```

If `iptables` is not running you'll get the following response:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

If `iptables` is running it will look similar to this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Write a script to check the status and grep for `Firewall is not running` and provide an return code for the script then use `monit` to run the script.

I didn't test it but it would look something like this:

```
check program iptables with path "/etc/init.d/iptables status"
    if status != 0 then alert
```

Comment: Your suggestion that "would look something like this" works great. Very good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An updated version of kenlukas's solution so make `monit` keep an eye on whether `iptables` is running might look like this:

```
check program iptables with path "/usr/bin/systemctl status iptables"
    start program = "/usr/bin/systemctl start iptables" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/usr/bin/systemctl stop iptables"
    if status != 0 then start
    if status != 0 for 2 cycles then alert

check program ip6tables with path "/usr/bin/systemctl status ip6tables"
    start program = "/usr/bin/systemctl start ip6tables" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/usr/bin/systemctl stop ip6tables"
    if status != 0 then start
    if status != 0 for 2 cycles then alert
```

**Note** that this won't work with Ubuntu 22.04, as `iptables` does not work as a service there.

**Note** that this may report false "not running" eventy, because `iptables` is "not a persistent service" (https://askubuntu.com/a/1332434/168515). It may still be a good indicator whether `iptables-restore` had run on boot.